# Mikrotik API remove command

Tags: php, mikrotik, router-os

I use a Mikrotik API, i can use **add** Command but I do not know how can use **remove** command.

example Adding VPN user:

```
$API->comm("/ppp/secret/add", array(
          "name"     => "user",
          "password" => "pass",
          "remote-address" => "172.16.1.10",
          "comment"  => "{new VPN user}",
          "service"  => "pptp",
));
```

Now how can Remove example VPN User1?

[http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Category:API](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Category%3aAPI)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $API->write('/ppp/secret/print', false);
 $API->write('?name=user', false);
 $API->write('=.proplist=.id');
 $ARRAYS = $API->read();


 $API->write('/ppp/secret/remove', false);
 $API->write('=.id=' . $ARRAYS[0]['.id']);
 $READ = $API->read();
```

Answer (score -1):

In mikrotik os terminal you can use remove like this:

- remove [find name=NAME]
- now test it in API